# testing relationships in rspec, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a test to check that an associated object exists and the relevant id is stored in the database.

A panel belongs to a page. A page has many panels.

A sample of the current errors I have is this

```
CorporatePanel 
     Failure/Error: @instance = corporate_panel
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Corporate page does not exist, Corporate page can't be blank
     # ./spec/support/project_helpers.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in setup_factories'
     # ./spec/models/corporate_panel_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Which I believe is caused because my test isnt creating an instance of page before a panel is created.

In my panel model I use this

```
  validate :check_associates

  private

  def check_associates
    associated_object_exists CorporatePage, :corporate_page_id
  end
```

The method 'associated_model_exists' is a helper

```
  def associated_object_exists(klass,fn,required=true)
    id=self.send(fn)
    id_setter=(fn.to_s+'=').to_sym
    unless klass.find_by_id(id)
      self.send(id_setter,nil)
      id=nil
    end
    if required==true and id.nil?
      errors.add(fn,"does not exist")
      return false
    end
  end
```

The Panel test looks like this,

```
    setup_factories

  before do
    @instance = corporate_panel
  end

  it { should belong_to(:corporate_page) }

  mandatory_integer :section
  mandatory_belongs_to CorporatePage
```

The madatory belongs_to looks like this

```
  def mandatory_belongs_to(model)
    context "#{model}" do
      context "where the id is incorrect" do
        before do
          allow(model).to receive(:find_by_id).and_return(nil)
        end
        it "should be invalid" do
          expect(@instance).to_not be_valid
        end
      end
      context "where the id is correct" do
        before do
          allow(model).to receive(:find_by_id).and_return(true)
        end
        it "should be valid" do
          expect(@instance).to be_valid
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

### Update

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :corporate_panel do
    corporate_page_id 1
    section 1
    # position 1
    panel_type "MyString"
    title "MyString"
    headline "MyString"
    body "MyText"
    workflow_state "MyString"
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :corporate_page do
    title "MyString"
    static_descriptor "Home"
    # workflow_state "MyString"
  end
end
```

How would I ensure that a page is created before the model, if that is even the problem?

Comment: You can just say: `validates :corporate_page, :presence => true` in your CorporatePanel model class and it should validate the presence of the association, why custom method, any specific reason? Also, can you paste the code which shows how you create corporate_panel at `@instance = corporate_panel` inside your spec?

Comment: @Surya thanks, ive added my factories

Comment: @Surya your suggestion still gives a failing test

Comment: Instead of `corporate_page_id 1` in `corporate_panel` factory. Say: `control_page` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you've defined your factory. It should create the appropriate association while creating the corporate panel. It should be something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :corporate_page do
    title "MyString"
    static_descriptor "Home"
    # workflow_state "MyString"
  end
end


FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :corporate_panel do
    corporate_page # this refers to the factory defined above!! and will create appropriate association.
    section 1
    # position 1
    panel_type "MyString"
    title "MyString"
    headline "MyString"
    body "MyText"
    workflow_state "MyString"
  end
end
```

Here are some links for further reading on factories: http://www.hiringthing.com/2012/08/17/rails-testing-factory-girl.html and https://github.com/brennovich/cheat-ruby-sheets/blob/master/factory_bot.md

Comment: Thanks @Surya! so simple, yet it eluded me for so long!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an association as recommended in Surya's answer. If you need more control over the creation of factories, you can also explicitly pass in the Corporate page when creating the CorporatePanel:

```
  let(:corporate_page) { FactoryGirl.create :corporate_page }
  let(:corporate_panel) { FactoryGirl.build :corporate_panel, corporate_page: corporate_page }
```

This might be preferable if you want to use the `:corporate_panel` factory in other examples *without* an associated `corporate_page`.

Comment: Good point but, as per my understanding OP had put validations in corporate panel for presence of `CorporatePage`, which means every time specs are run there will be an invalid factory for corporate panel which can lead to confusing spec errors.